# Where is the string allocated in runtime C?

Tags: c, malloc

When I use char pointer to a string as:

```
char *a = "Hello";
```

will the C run-time library create a memory spape for that string? If it does, where is the string "Hello" allocated, in the heap or in the stack?

Comment: You can think of it as being allocated in the same place that a read-only (ie, `const`) global variable would reside.

Comment: I got it!!! So the string will be put in data section at compiler time ??

Comment: You should see it somewhere in the compiled object or executable, and it will be designated for a particular section.